# python multiprocessing process count

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
#coding:utf-8

import sys
import time
import os
import multiprocessing

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.progress = 0
        self.task_info = None

    def init(self):
        pass

    def status(self):
        pass

    def set_task_info(self, task_info):
        self.task_info = task_info

    def run(self, worker_status_meta_dict):
        print multiprocessing.current_process()
        print "process is %d" % self.progress
        while self.progress < 5:
            self.progress = self.progress +1
            worker_status_meta_dict['state'] = 0
            worker_status_meta_dict['status'] = "running"
            time.sleep(2)
        worker_status_meta_dict['state'] = 1
        worker_status_meta_dict['status'] = "succeeded"
        print "bavscan worker finished..."      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker = Worker()
    worker_process_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=Worker.run, args=(worker, worker_process_dict))
    process.start()
    time.sleep(60)
```

This is a simple demo for python multiprocess.
The main process invoke the Worker.run method in a subprocess with multiprocessing.Process.
When run it in wondows 7, the main process will lauch two subprocess.

[image: enter image description]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I only lautch one subprocess, but there are two subprocess.

Comment: The output you provided doesn't correspond with your code - there must be `"process is ..."` lines. Run exactly the code you provided and show the output.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem in the "Python27\Lib\multiprocessing__init__.py"

```
def Manager():
    '''
    Returns a manager associated with a running server process

    The managers methods such as `Lock()`, `Condition()` and `Queue()`
    can be used to create shared objects.
    '''
    from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
    m = SyncManager()
    m.start()
    return m
```

m.start() will lauch a subprocess to start the manager.